# Rollback an executed query

Tags: mysql, rollback

Suppose I have a field(**age**) with integer values like:

```
age(23,34,12,23,14,55)
```

and I need to update all values to 18 so I created an update query like `update person set age=18 where condition`, If I want to revert the query i.e what will be rollback query I mean how can I get old values of the field.

Comment: What language are you using to make the query? Are you doing it directly in MySQL? Typically, rolling back is an internal mechanism handled by the DB. As long as you haven't committed the transaction (and don't have auto commit enabled) then you should simply be able to `ROLLBACK` and the DB engine will handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, if you committed the query. Only inside transactions you can roll back the changes that haven't been committed yet.

You have to keep track of previous values if you want to have some kind of a rollback mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql Workbench don't support rollback option.
You can use Toad for Mysql since it supports rollback options.
you can download the link from here:

http://toad-for-mysql.en.softonic.com/